# How to extract needed informations from text?

Tags: json, algorithm, parsing, time-complexity

I have a lot of publications from which I want to parse and extract needed and useful informations.
Suppose I have this publication `A`

> 2 places available tomorrow at 12AM from California to Alaska. Cost is 100$. And this is my phone number 814141243.

Another one `B`

> One place available to Texas. We will be leaving at 13PM today. Cost will be discussed. Tel: 2323575456.

I want to find the best way to extract data from these publications using an algorithm with linear complexity.
For each publication, the algorithm must produce this:

```
{ "publication": [
      { "id":"A",
        "date":"26/01/2016",
        "time":"12AM",
        "from":"California",
        "to":"Alaska",
        "cost":"100$",
        "nbrOfPlaces":"2",
        "tel":"814141243" },
      { "id":"B",
        "date":"25/01/2016",
        "time":"13PM",
        "from":"",
        "to":"Texas",
        "cost":"",
        "nbrOfPlaces":"1",
        "tel":"2323575456" }
     ]
 }
```

So i want the maximum of informations from those publications. But obviously the problem is with the the words chosen by the writer of the publication and how they are structured. Simply, publications don't have common structure so that i can't easily parse and extract needed informations.

Is there any concepts or paradigms that deal with this kind of problem?

**Note:** I can't force publications' writers to respect a precise structure for the text.

Comment: You are trying to convert unstructured data into structured one. That's much more complex than you think it is.

Comment: Yes @amit . That is exactly what i want. I have thought for example to think about repetitive words from previous publications, so the algorithm must learn from the past. Isn't it somehow related to artificial intelligence?

Comment: I suggest you study a book on natural language processing. It won't really help you solve this problem, but it will give you a perspective on its magnitude.

Comment: Yes! It is about NLP, there is no other way and it is not easy!

Comment: Given that OP's input is implied to be arbitrary natural text, no amount of hacking will get him an effective answer.    He either has to a) accept poor results, b) constrain his inputs to some mechanically interpretable format, or c) solve the natural language parsing problem.   I'm under the impression he does not know enough about parsing to really tackle this [read that NLP book for starters!] and have any chance of success.

Comment: A stunningly common error made by many people is that "artificial intelligence" and "machine learning" are some kind of magic machinery that reduces hard problems to trivial ones.  Its not true.  Don't count on it to save you.

Comment: The examples are not really "arbitrary natural text"; they use a small set of fixed expressions, like a number followed by "places", or an amount preceded by "cost" ... surely the number of possibilities is small enough to get decent results in many cases? I understand it can never work perfectly, but maybe the OP doesn't need a 100% success rate.

Comment: Yes @m69, I don't need 100% success rate

Comment: So what success rate do you need?

Comment: Can you post or link to a larger sample of real (-istic) input? Your two examples make it look feasible, but they may be the best-case-scenario.

Comment: @m69 all the examples are similar to those given above

Comment: @IraBaxter Let's say I want 95% success rate

Comment: OK, show us 1000 random real samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems all the comments are discouraging you from trying to do this. However, the variation in the text seems quite limited; I can see a simple algorithm finding the info in most (but obviously not all) input. I'd try something like this:

- Split the text into parts on interpunction: `.;?!()` and then look at the text line by line; this will help determine context.
- Use a list of often-used words and abbreviations to determine where each bit of info is located.
- Date: look for the names of days or months, "today", "tomorrow" or typical notations of dates like "12/31".
- Time: look for combinations with "AM", "PM", "morning", "noon" etc., or typical time notations like "12:30"
- Route: look for "from" and "to", possibly combined with "going", "driving", "traveling" etc. and maybe look for capital letters to find the place names (and/or use a list of often-used destinations).
- Cost: look for a line that contains "$" or "cost" or "price" or similar, and find the number, or typical "to be discussed" or "to be determined" phrasing.
- Places: look for "places", "seats", "people" and find the number, or "place", "seat" or "person" and conclude there is 1 place.
- Phone: look for a sequence of digits of a certain length, with maybe spaces or `./()` between them.

If you're certain that you've found a part of the info, mark it so that it isn't used again; e.g. if you find "8.30" together with "AM", it's obviously a time. However, if you just find "8.30" it could be a date or a time, or even $8.30.

You'll have to take into account that a small percentage of input will never be machine-readable; something like "off to the big apple at the crak-o-dawn, wanna come with? you pay the gas-moh-nay!" will always need human interpretation.